# C3.js renders slow in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-10, c3.js

I'm having a dashboard containing ten c3.js graphs.
Rendering takes 900 ms in Chrome, but 4600 ms in Internet Explorer 11 (10-modus).
When profiling, the getBoundingClientRect method takes a lot of time (2995 ms).
I already tried putting the dom element to visibility hidden, etc.
Any idea why and how to improve the Internet Explorer performance?

Comment: Can you please tell which version of c3js and d3js you are using.   
Same here, our web app is slow on IE10 and fastest in Chrome latest.
Also check out c3js discussion forum  :-https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/c3js

Comment: @Chetan d3js: 3.5.6, c3js: 0.4.10

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following CSS solved the problem entirely: `svg { position: absolute !important }`